# DynamoDBVersionAttribute for a frequency field

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a DDB table, 4 attributes, key (PK - a string), date (sort/range key), status, frequency.
I have multiple clients that will write to this table based on the 'key' and date value

I want to increment frequency every time a client makes a write.

Can I just use DynamoDBVersionAttribute on an int field and use this as a proxy for frequency?

I understand this is not meant for this use case, but I want to avoid having to first read and then write the item. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already doing an update expression, just add an `ADD` action to increment the frequency by 1. The `ADD` action doesn't need to know the original value to increment it.

See the example from the docs here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement